# Не работает ImageSource.FromStream Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, android, ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Нужно загрузить картинку с использованием HttpClient. Но нижеприведенный код не работает. В чем может быть причина?

```
            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                var imageResponse = client.GetStreamAsync(new Uri(
                        "https://images.pexels.com/photos/414612/pexels-photo-414612.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=750&w=1260"))
                    .Result;
                Image.Source = ImageSource.FromStream(() => imageResponse);
            }
```

С помощью ImageSource.FromUri картинка показывается исправно, но мне необходимо будет использовать NTLM аутентификацию, поэтому без ImageSource.FromStream и HttpClient не обойтись.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Путем экспериментов нашел рабочий вариант.

```
            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                var response = client.GetAsync(new Uri(
                        "https://images.pexels.com/photos/414612/pexels-photo-414612.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=750&w=1260"))
                    .Result;
                if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
                {
                    var stream = response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
                    Image.Source = ImageSource.FromStream(() => stream.Result);
                }
            }
```

Так и не понял, почему предыдущий код не работает.